# solar panel model as constant current source + initial values

Tags: solar-cell, matlab, simulink

I have created a simple solar panel model in Matlab, using the diode equivalent model. The basic equation is as follows:

```
I = Iph - I0*(exp((V+Rs*I)/(Vtherm*a))-1) - (V+Rs*I)/Rsh
```

where Iph is the photocurrent, I0 the saturation current, V the voltage over the panel, Rs the total series resistance, Vtherm the thermal voltage and Rsh the total shunt resistance.

I've plotted the IV and PV curves and they look right. I'd like to use the model as an embedded matlab function in a Simulink model, but have troubling getting it to work.

As mentioned above I solve for I within my model. But I'm having trouble getting my head around how to then solve for V because both terms depend on each other, and the external resistance as well. I could now use Newton-Raphson or other numerical method to get V from the above equation, but how can I take into account the presence of an external load?
[image]
In the model above I haven't explicitly solved for V and I've just added the current I get from the above equation as a constant source. I'm not sure whether this is the right way to go, however... If I now want to add more panels in series, how can I do so without adding ideal current sources in series as well, which is clearly unphysical?

I don't know how to choose the initial values for V and I, because I need bot to solve for I in the next time step. If I choose I=0 and V=0, the I value is clearly Iph as other terms cancel out. But that, surely, cannot be right as it's the photocurrent of the panel..!

Any help clearing this up would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using MATLAB 2015 or above you can directly use PV panel from simulink. There are models specified already or you can define by yourself.

Comment: I followed this link https://environmentalsystemsresearch.springeropen.com/track/pdf/10.1186/s40068-015-0047-9?site=environmentalsystemsresearch.springeropen.com